.NET 6.0 and EF Core: How do I unit test EF Core LINQ Queries with a LEFT JOIN?
I have a LINQ query which performs a LEFT JOIN on two tables:

var leftJoinData = (from costDetails in dbContext.CostDetails
                    join orderInformation in dbContext.OrderInformation on costDetails.FK_INVTABLEUID equals orderInformation.FK_INVTABLEUID
                       into completeInformationList
                       from ci in completeInformationList.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select new
                       {
                           ci.OrderId,
                           cost = costDetails.MaximumRetailPrice
                       }).AsNoTracking().ToList();

I want to test the method executing this query, but when I test after mocking the db set(using Moq), I get System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source'). But when I remove the LEFT JOIN and instead perform and INNER JOIN, that is, when I remove the  completeInformationList.DefaultIfEmpty() call, I am able to test it.

have you read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/?

@sommmen I did go through it, but did not find anything on testing of left joins.
